# heroku java web server deployment using sun httpserver

Tags: java, heroku, webserver

I've built a small demo server on my computer with Java sun httpserver library.

Now, I want to go public and deploy it to heroku.

put it simply, this is my Main.java class (below).

It is being build as a Maven project.

I connected herkou with my maven project (code sits on github) and the compile and run phase with maven gives me "build success".

But, when I am trying to access my server as I did in my local enviromnet (http://localhost:8000/test), when I enter this url (my herkou site): https://shaffa.herokuapp.com:8000/test I am now getting a message saying: "page cannot be loaded".

Does herkou automaticlly run my main method in maven project (I need it to be the case since my server starts at my main method)..

if it is the case, what else could be the problem?

Thanks!

```
public class Main {
    static MySQLQueryExecutor mySQLQueryExecutor=MySQLQueryExecutor.getInstance();
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8000), 0);
        server.createContext("/test", new MyHandler());

        server.setExecutor(null);
        server.start();
        System.out.println(server.getAddress());
    }



    static class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {

        public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
            String response = "This is Get response";
            t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
            OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
            os.write(response.getBytes());
            os.close();
        }
    }


}
```

building log:

```
-----> Java app detected
-----> Installing OpenJDK 1.8... done
-----> Installing Maven 3.3.9... done
-----> Executing: mvn -DskipTests clean dependency:list install
       [INFO] Scanning for projects...
       [INFO]                                                                         
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] Building my_demo 1.0-SNAPSHOT
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ my_demo ---
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:list (default-cli) @ my_demo ---
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ my_demo ---
       [WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
       [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /tmp/build_0073fd7c9decf8f53d270853eac0864e/Matoy7-ShaffaServer-dd12826/src/main/resources
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ my_demo ---
       [INFO] No sources to compile
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ my_demo ---
       [WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
       [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /tmp/build_0073fd7c9decf8f53d270853eac0864e/Matoy7-ShaffaServer-dd12826/src/test/resources
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ my_demo ---
       [INFO] No sources to compile
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ my_demo ---
       [INFO] Tests are skipped.
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ my_demo ---
       [WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!
       [INFO] Building jar: /tmp/build_0073fd7c9decf8f53d270853eac0864e/Matoy7-ShaffaServer-dd12826/target/my_demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ my_demo ---
       [INFO] Installing /tmp/build_0073fd7c9decf8f53d270853eac0864e/Matoy7-ShaffaServer-dd12826/target/my_demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to /app/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/yotam/my_demo/1.0-SNAPSHOT/my_demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
       [INFO] Installing /tmp/build_0073fd7c9decf8f53d270853eac0864e/Matoy7-ShaffaServer-dd12826/pom.xml to /app/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/yotam/my_demo/1.0-SNAPSHOT/my_demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] Total time: 2.365 s
       [INFO] Finished at: 2017-05-08T16:28:54+00:00
       [INFO] Final Memory: 16M/167M
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> (none)
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 48M
-----> Launching...
       Released v7
       https://shaffa.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Application Logs

```
2017-05-08T14:17:52.452910+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=shaffa.herokuapp.com request_id=5f365605-2f15-45d7-a043-5aea122ab4b8 fwd="109.64.111.39" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-05-08T16:28:47.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user yz@gmail.com
2017-05-08T16:28:49.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user yz@gmail.com
2017-05-08T16:29:00.835249+00:00 app[api]: Deploy dd12826 by user yz@gmail.com
2017-05-08T16:29:00.835249+00:00 app[api]: Release v7 created by user yz@gmail.com
2017-05-08T16:28:47.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2017-05-08T16:29:03.635910+00:00 app[api]: Deploy dd12826 by user yz@gmail.com
2017-05-08T16:28:49.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2017-05-08T16:29:03.635910+00:00 app[api]: Release v8 created by user yz@gmail.com
2017-05-08T16:29:08.055046+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=shaffa.herokuapp.com request_id=c06affca-0979-4e7c-aafe-69e5296a33c0 fwd="109.64.111.39" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-05-08T16:29:08.706745+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=shaffa.herokuapp.com request_id=f11fe11a-a99a-4f19-bbff-34b0a84fa1f3 fwd="109.64.111.39" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: run `heroku logs -t` after deploying, and post the output here.

Comment: Also, what does your `Procfile` contain?

Comment: added in original msg

Comment: also I don't have procfile and don't have dyno

Comment: I am not using CLI but dashboard. How can I create procfile+ dyno? is it mandatory?

Answer (score 0):

You need to scale your app up to at least one dyno in the Resources tab of the dashboard.